# Retrieving Users Gender While Google SignIn using Firebase but not getting all users Gender?

Tags: android, google-signin

**Scenario:**

I am trying to login with `GOOGLE SIGN IN` using `Firebase Google Login` in my android app, my basic need is that to retrieve `USER` gender while `USER` sign in my app.

**Problem:**

Even if I am getting gender of `USERS` but **NOT All** `USERS`, so where is the problem because getting only some users gender is quite strange, **so my question is that why i am not getting all users gender while login?**

```
public void performFirebaseLogin(GoogleSignInAccount acct, final Context context, final LoginSPrefRepositoryImpl loginSPrefRepositoryImpl) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        final GoogleAccountCredential googleCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                    context, Collections.singleton(Scopes.PROFILE));
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener((Activity) context, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            if (user != null) {
                            //here i am calling profile detail of user
                                new GetProfileDetails(user, googleCredential,loginSPrefRepositoryImpl).execute();
                            } else {
                                    onLoginListener.onFailure("Login Failed");
                            }
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }


//here i am retrieving user's information  

class GetProfileDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Person> {

        private PeopleService ps;
        private int authError = -1;
        private FirebaseUser user;
        private LoginSPrefRepositoryImpl loginSPrefRepositoryImpl;

        GetProfileDetails(FirebaseUser user, GoogleAccountCredential credential, LoginSPrefRepositoryImpl loginSPrefRepositoryImpl) {

            this.loginSPrefRepositoryImpl = loginSPrefRepositoryImpl;
            this.user = user;
            credential.setSelectedAccount(
                    new Account(user.getEmail(), "com.google"));

            HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

            ps = new PeopleService.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Google Sign In Quickstart")
                    .build();
        }

        @Override
        protected Person doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Person meProfile = null;
            try {
                meProfile = ps
                        .people()
                        .get("people/me")
                        .setPersonFields("genders")
                        .execute();
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                authError = 0;
            } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                authError = 1;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                authError = 2;
            }
            return meProfile;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Person meProfile) {
            //mainAct.printBasic();
            if (authError == 0) { //app has been revoke, re-authenticated required.
                //mainAct.reqPerm();
            } else if (authError == 1) {
                Log.w(TAG, "People API might not enable at" +
                        " https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/people.googleapis.com/?project=<project name>");
            } else if (authError == 2) {
                Log.w(TAG, "API io error");
            } else {
                if (meProfile != null) {
                    // Log.d("kkkk", "" + meProfile.getGenders());
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(meProfile.getGenders());
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        String gender = jsonObject.getString("formattedValue");
                        loginSPrefRepositoryImpl.isLoggedIn();
                        loginSPrefRepositoryImpl.setGender(gender);
                        onLoginListener.onSuccess(user);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        onLoginListener.onFailure("Something went wrong !");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe `getGenders()` is empty if the user does not specify their gender?

Comment: but i set gender while creating a account !

Comment: Do you *require* a user to specify their gender before they can create an account, or is it optional?

Comment: actually i am taking from user google account , its not optional !

Comment: Do all the google accounts have a gender? Maybe you don't have the proper permissions on all accounts. I don't think my account has a gender but I could be wrong.

Comment: but my account having gender info !

Comment: Google Account can show the info but user can hide the info as a privacy setting. I have verified my account, it indicates my gender status but I can hide the info saying "Rather not say". Probably some user have added the option not to reveal the info.

Comment: @DeepP can help me , how can i check that !

Comment: https://myaccount.google.com/privacy?hl=en, It will show your gmaill account details. In that you can view the Gender flag, you can show or hide .

Comment: @DeepP Thanks , its working too , any hacks we get gender even if its in hide mode ?

Comment: I fear there wont be any hacks in this regard. It comes under privacy rules and hence its a serious issue if you were able to get the info thro some hacks

Comment: @DeepP okay , thank you so much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that `gender` should be explicitly shared by the user on his `Google +` account. I suggest you to experiment by yourself.

1. Go to this page https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get
2. Type `resourceName` = `people/me` and `personFields` = `genders`
3. Do the request, most likely you'll get the response with only `resourceName` and `etag` fields.
4. Now go to https://plus.google.com/u/0/me page, which will open your G+ page and open Account Settings. Or you can open https://aboutme.google.com/u/0/ page directly.
5. Click on the icon next to your Gender. This is the visibility setting, so user can choose if he wants to make his gender public, private or share only with circles. I suggest you to try different visibility options and check how it changes response at the step #3.

TL;DR: There is `Gender` visibility setting on G+, user may have chosen not to share his gender and there is no dedicated profile scope to request during auth for it. This setting is competely private.

Comment: do you have any other idea to get gender ?(even his google plus gender setting is private).

Comment: @kdblue if this setting is private, there is no way to get a gender

Comment: you can change the gender visibility of your profile from this link: https://aboutme.google.com/